# Zigbee Home Automation

Tags: zigbee, home-automation

I am looking for the device ID of humidity sensor for Zigbee Home Automation Profile, but did not find it anywhere. Can anyone tell me what is the device ID for humidity sensor? Or is there any other way to associate humidity sensor as an endpoint?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a device ID for a humidity sensor.  You could do a temperature sensor (0x0302) and add support for the humidity measurement cluster.  This is awkward if you don't have anyway to measure temperature though.

From my experience, the humidity cluster is generally added in addition to some other device type (motion, door, thermostat, etc).  I haven't come across a humidity only sensor.